# Symfony 5 error 500 when performing an AJAX query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I'm working on a mini web project, so I considered it as an opportunity to learn Symfony framework.

So the thing is I'm developing a simple game and the players can store some items in their inventory, or change their coordinates and to do so dynamically I thought about using Ajax but each time the query is not being executed and the console shows me:

> 500
> Internal Server Error

and also the route isn't being mapped correctly by the twig path function.

Here's the html.twig file containing a portion of the JS code (to test if it works I inserted it directly to the html.twig but in reality I want it on an external js file because I have many interactions and functions to implement already coded but unfortunately I always face the same problem)

```
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>{% block title %}LIP{% endblock %}</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
{% block stylesheets %} 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-    awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq  /sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
    crossorigin=""/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/signInUp.css')}}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/Homestyle.css')}}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/Playerstyle.css')}}"/>

{% endblock %}
<link rel = "icon" href =  "{{asset("Icons/eiffel64.png")}}" type = "image/x-icon"> 
       {% block javascripts %}
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512- XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
        crossorigin=""></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("executing internal ajax!");
            //var idMagasin = $('#choixMagasin option:selected').attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "{{path('move_player')}}",
                //data: {id: idMagasin},
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
        
                    //var periode = data.periode;
                    //console.log(donnees);
                }
            });
        });
     </script>
    {% endblock %}

 </head>
 {% block body %}
 <body>

  <div class="section1" id="mapid">
  

  </div>


  <div class="section2" id="playerInterface">
  {% if app.user %}
    <a href="{{path('logout_Player')}}" id="logout">Déconnexion</a>
  {% else %}
  {% endif %}  
  <div move-path="{{path('move_player')}}"></div>

  </div>
  <div class="footer">
  <p>2020 Copyright ©  ENSG Géomatique Developped by MaghraouiDE & Namekon Teulong PF</p>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ENSGeomatique" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
  <a href="https://fr.linkedin.com/edu/ecole-nationale-des-sciences-g%C3%A9ographiques-12351" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
  <img src="{{asset('Icons/logo_ensg.png')}}"  class="logo"/>
</div>{% if app.user is defined %}
        {% set player_data = {
                pseudo: app.user.Username,
                longitude: app.user.longitude,
                latitude: app.user.latitude,
                inventaire: app.user.inventaire,

            } %}
            <div data-player='{{ player_data | json_encode | raw }}'>
            </div>
        {% endif %}

            


    {% block javascript %}
    <script src="{{asset('js/code.js')}}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
    {% endblock %}
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here's my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use App\Entity\Items;
use App\Entity\Players;
use App\Entity\Inventaire;


class InteractionsController extends AbstractController
{
/**
 * @Route("/interactions", name="interactions")
 */
public function index(): Response
{
    return $this->render('interactions/index.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'InteractionsController',
    ]);
 }
/**
 * @Route("/interactions/move_player",name="move_player")
 */
public function moveplayer(Request $request,EntityManagerInterface $em){
    $player = $this->getUser();
    return new JsonResponse(array("username"=>$player->getUsername(),"longitude"=>$player->getLongitude()));
}
}

/**
 * @Route("/interactions/affiche_scenario", name="affiche_scenario")
 */
public function afficheScenario(Request $request){
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Scenarios::class);
        return new JsonResponse($repository->findBy($request->request->get("num_scenario")));
    }
    else{
        return new JsonResponse(array["error"=>"Something went wrong!"]);

    }
}
}

/**
 * @Route("/interactions/add_item",name="add_item")
 */
public function addItem(Request $request,EntityManagerInterface $em){

    $player = $this->getUser();
    $inventaire=$player->getInventaire();
    return new JsonResponse(array("player"=>$player,"inventaire"=>$inventaire->getItem_id()));
    
    }
```

I removed the different processing from these controllers because I just want to test the JSON response which doesn't work, I should also add that I tried to use other method (ajax query in classical JS without jQuery, with using XMLHttpRequest and also fetch API which I have already used them in other applications but I can't figure out what am I doing wrong here on Symfony environment.

Comment: Do you see any critical or error in you Symfony's logs

Comment: I would recommend you first try to access your controller from another client such as curl or postman.  to make sure your call is being configured correctly and you controller is listening where you expect. Its common to have the wrong url and get a 500

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer to this issue that i've faced is silly! i just forgot to import the JsonResponse class, that's why the error 500:internal server error, i hope that this could be usefull for some people.
Thanks for everyone who spent time reading my post and trying to help.

Comment: a other problem, if you have don't access of file, for example:
You are a chown user:user and the send file has www-data:www-data ;-)